# git - automatically git reset after trying to pick a commit that I already have

Tags: git

I'm trying to `git cherry-pick start..end`, and I already have a lot of commits commited that are in `start..end` and each time it tries to pick one there is I get such message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 9 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You are currently cherry-picking commit e0a5d27bed8.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

If you wish to skip this commit, use:

    git reset

Then "git cherry-pick --continue" will resume cherry-picking
the remaining commits.
```

I have tried using `rev-list` like this: `git rev-list --remove-empty --reverse start..end . | git cherry-pick --stdin`

with adding `--remove-empty` and a `.` but that does not help.

Is there a way to do to skip these type of commits?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `git cherry-pick` rather than `git rebase`? I don't know if it makes a difference, but it might.

Comment: Why not resolve the conflict?

Comment: @matt theres no conflict. its when it tries to pick a commit and the changes are already done in my tree

Comment: Oh! So maybe rebase would be better, because it knows how to skip those. Rebase is repeated cherry pick, so you should get the desired result.

Comment: @matt the thing is. my tree has no git history for those. this is a OEM linux kernel source drop (1 commit kernel)

Comment: *the thing is. my tree has no git history for those* -- this is the part that kills the ability to automate it through existing Git commands. Anything that would find the commits already contained, has no commits to search through. You'll have to do this the hard way *or* write your own tool that tries each cherry-pick to see if it works, fails with a conflict, or does nothing.